# Uninstall resetting phpmyadmin installation

Tags: phpmyadmin

i'm in trouble with phpmyadmin since i would to start learn.

i'm on mac with OSX 10.10.5, recently i've perfomed some installation using bitnami 4.3.1-1 stack but after 2 or 3 months i've forgot phpmyadmin login and password. Since i don't work at all with wordpress, i've performed an uninstall of entire folder using uninstaller provided with it but after reinstalling bitnami (and phpmyadmin) i'm no longer allowed to access phpmyadmin login. It says incorrect login data.

even uninstalling the entire stack and reinstalling, nothing seems to change in login page. Start thinking there are some credentials stored somewhere in some hidden file or DB.

after so many hours of frustation, fails and reinstall, i've decided to ask you a solution to this. Is there a way to complete uninstall all password and credentials and start over with a fresh install? Seriously, i don't want to format entire hdd. I've googled a lot and tried some solutions with no results. From terminal to changing AllowNoPassword to true but nothing seems restore phpmyadmin to first install. Can anyone help me? Any tips will be much appreciated.

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

By default, in a fresh Bitnami stack installation, phpMyAdmin user is `root` and the password is the one you write during the installation process.

For example, if your password is `1234abcd` and your Apache port is 8080, you should be able to access from your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/, using `root` and `1234abcd`.

Note that those are the credentials to access MySQL. You could also reset your MySQL root password following the guide below:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/MySQL#How_to_reset_the_MySQL_root_password.3f

This would be the new password for phpMyAdmin too.

I hope it helps.